# Poetry shell command prompt: what gives the (base) part?

Tags: git, shell, python-venv, python-poetry

I am developing python projects under git control using poetry to manage my venvs.

From my project's directory I issue a "poetry shell" command and my new shell command prompt becomes something like:

```
(isagog-ai-py3.10) (base) bob@Roberts-Mac-mini isagog-ai %
```

where the first part in bracket gives me the name pf the project and the python version I'm using, and the last part of the prompt is my current directory name.

But what is it that gives me the "(base)" part? I'm actually working on a "dev" branch.

Comment: Looks like `base` environment from `conda`. Do you use `conda` to install Python or packages?

Comment: Very good observation! :) Here's the situation. I have used conda as my package manager until yesterday. Since a few weeks I have switched to poetry but yes when I exit from the "poetry shell" I see the (base) conda prompt. So guess you hit the bullseye !!! :) That (base) is the conda generated prompt! Want to repost this as the answer which I'd happily vote? Thanks a lot and take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `base` environment from `conda`.